# Laravel log keeps giving Redis not found error while running

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-8, phpredis

I am running on docker and nginx and Laravel log keeps giving redis not found error while running.

[image]

[image]

My Configurations:

1. file `.env`:

   CACHE_DRIVER=redis

   SESSION_DRIVER=redis

   MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

   REDIS_HOST=redis

   REDIS_PASSWORD=null

   REDIS_PORT=6379
2. file `database.php`:

   'redis' => [

   ```
       'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

       'options' => [
           'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
           'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
       ],

       'default' => [
           'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
           'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
           'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
           'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
           'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
       ],

       'cache' => [
           'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
           'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
           'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
           'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
           'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
       ],
   ]
   ```

I also installed sudo apt-get install php8.0-redis but still not working.

There are a lot of people asking about this problem but I haven't found a good way to solve this problem. I don't know if there is any way you can make it work as it should or can you turn off redis?

Comment: I think you did install `redis` but never enabled it. Can you do `phpinfo()` and look for `Redis` and see if it exists in there and if it enabled?

Comment: I used `phpinfo()` to check and found that redis exists and is enabled and still gives the same error. Don't know if you have any other way to get rid of this error?